# Which cable will work with my headset?

Tags: audio, cable, microphone, splitter, 3.5mm

Today my audio/mic splitter cable broke, and I'm looking to buy a new one, however I'm scared I'm going to buy the wrong one.

The headset description for the cable is the following: 
*3.5mm 4 Pole Audio/Mic* 
*3.5 mm Audio Splitter Cable*

The following link is the link to where I purchased the headset (so you can get a better idea on what I'm talking about / specifications): 
[Gaming Headset](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826140142&cm_re=gaming_headset_detachable-_-26-140-142-_-Product)

So I've been searching around, and I found the following item: [Audio Splitter Cable Dual 3.5mm Male to Single Female](http://www.gearbest.com/cables-adapter/pp_160521.html) 
I'm not sure whether this is the correct cord to buy or not, and I don't want to buy it not knowing 100% if it will work or not.

If someone could help me out and tell me if that's the correct cord, and if  it's not, help me find the correct one, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks guys. I hope I wrote my question correct. Have a good night.

Comment: The audio/mic version is the one you want.  The audio splitter is for connection 2 audio only headsets to the same computer.  The problem is you're calling the device you want a splitter, and technically it's not a splitter.

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible to answer as we do not know the pinout. The 4 sections are left ear, right ear, ground & mic. They can be in different orders. Apple use one pinout, some android use another and the rest of android devices use a third configuration. Spec sheet just says "mobile devices" which is useless.

To get a definitive answer you would have to use a multimeter to check continuity to the pins by dismantling the old splitter cable. Alternatively, trial and error. The new splitter you linked to lists compatibility for different systems so I am suspect of it correctness.